# How do you test what elements a jquery-ui sortable element is connected to?

Tags: jquery-ui

I would like test what jquery-ui sortable elements are connected. Is this information stored somewhere, or is there some way to figure it out?

For example if I have four lists, and I want to see if any of them are connect and if so which list they are connected to how would I do that?

Here's a code example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mL1e0mLh/

```js
$('#sortable1').sortable({ connectWith: '#sortable4' });
$('#sortable2').sortable();
$('#sortable3').sortable();
$('#sortable4').sortable({ connectWith: '#sortable1' });

function getConnectedList(element) {
  var connectedElement = null;
  // Do something
  return connectedElement;
}

getConnectedList(document.getElementById('sortable1')); // Should return element with ID #sortable4
getConnectedList(document.getElementById('sortable2')); // Should return null
getConnectedList(document.getElementById('sortable3')); // Should return null
getConnectedList(document.getElementById('sortable4')); // Should return element with ID #sortable1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [instance method](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-instance) to do this:

```
function getConnectedList(element) {
  return element.sortable( "instance" ).options.connectWith;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6s8nehdx/)**

Comment: Just a note, you can also get the value of `options.connectWith` using the jQuery method `.data()`, like this: `$(element).data('ui-sortable').options.connectWith`. I had to do it this way because for some reason I kept getting the error "Error: no such method 'instance' for sortable widget instance" when I tried using `$(element).sortable('instance').options.connectWith`.